# How do I tell if a metal can is safe to bake in?

Tags: baking, food-safety, equipment, bread

I'm hoping to make some Boston brown bread in the near future, and the recipe I plan to use (http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/10/gluten-free-boston-brown-bread-recipe.html) calls for 'unlined 28-ounce cans', but doesn't specify what it means by 'unlined'.  Other recipes I've looked at either say 'any metal can' or just say to use a loaf pan, and I've found lists of which brands of canned food don't use BPA in the lining of their cans, but nothing listing completely unlined cans.

Is there a website somewhere that lists either where I can find food-safe unlined cans, or which types of lining are safe to bake in?  (Or am I just overthinking this, since presumably the cans are exposed to equal or higher temperatures during the canning process?)

Thanks all!

Comment: see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21255/can-i-use-a-reused-can-for-serving-food and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30498/is-it-ok-to-store-open-cans-in-the-fridge

Comment: Unlined means no other material on the inside; usually that's a plastic coating.

Comment: Bisphenol A boils at 360.5 deg C at 760 mm Hg (681 °F) https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Bisphenol_A#section=Odor , so you'll have a tough time burnining it out with a conventional oven. Perhaps a blowtorch, but this sounds very much like an **outside** project. You don't want to be melting any solder while doing it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use tin bread molds for baking. They are 'unlined', and so far, they seem to be safe enough. I suppose lining also refers to teflon coating, which is also safe for baking.

Try your luck with tin, the link below has a image for a bread mold similar to those I use.

http://www.elmaral.com/images/moldebudiningles%20graneado..jpg